# Scheduling recurring payments with end date on stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to create a 6-week course, where the customer signs up for the course and then gets automatically charged for portion of the course fee each week.

I am able to create the 6-week subscription schedule but I am struggling to figure out how to get create a checkout session where the customer can put in their credit card information and start paying for this 6-week subscription.

I am creating the subscription schedule like this:

```
// First, I create a price object which returns to me a price object with id: price_IK...
const price = await stripe.prices.create({
  unit_amount: 100,
  currency: 'usd',
  recurring: {interval: 'week'},
  product: 'prod_LDD...',
});

// Then, I create a subscription schedule object which returns to make subscriptionSchedule object with id: sub_sched_1K...
const schedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({
  start_date: 'now',
  end_behavior: 'release',
  phases: [
    {
      items: [{ price: 'price_1K...', quantity: 1 }],
      iterations: 6,
    },
  ],
});
```

**Now, how do I display a create a checkout session with this subscription schedule to allow a customers to put in their credit card information and start paying for this subscription?**

For recurring payments with no end date, I'm able to just set a subscription payment in the checkout session itself:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  mode: 'subscription',
  line_items: [
    {
      price: price_1K...,
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/canceled.html',
});
```

I want to do something similar for recurring payments with an end date but don't seem to be able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1. Create a Checkout Session, mode = 'subscription' with a trial. When it's still in trial, [create a Subscription Schedule to apply to that Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription) and modify the schedule as you want.
2. Create a Checkout Session, mode = 'setup' to collect your customer payment info. Then later on [create Subscription Schedule specifying that Customer Id](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#start-subscription-future)

Comment: Thank you — super helpful!! I'm guessing with option #1, when the customer goes to the checkout session, it says that they are going to be charged weekly for forever? Since the subscription schedule is only applied after the checkout session is done? It seems like option #2 is probably the cleanest method though has the disadvantage of never being super clear to the customer that their credit card is going to start getting charged now.

Comment: You are correct that with #1 Checkout page will say weekly (but won't explicitly mention "forever"). Agree that #2 seems cleaner. However as you said you would need to somehow communicate to your customer that you are using their card info to charge later