# Stripe Checkout Session

Tags: php, stripe-payments

How to add start date in Stripe Checkout Session Subscription?

I am using stripe checkout-session with a daily subscription, but I want to start the subscription on my scheduled date.
For example, A campaign starts from 21 of April, and today is the 1st of April, I wanna subscribe to this campaign today but the amount deduction will start from the 21st.
I don't want to use a trial.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Checkout Session, mode = 'setup' to collect your customer payment info. Then later on https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#start-subscription-future

Ref:
[Scheduling recurring payments with end date on stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290530/scheduling-recurring-payments-with-end-date-on-stripe)